# Why don't electrons just "pile up" on the positive side of a battery?

Tags: batteries, dc

Consider an extremely simple circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBwkma.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since electrons are negatively charged, the current will flow towards the positive side of the battery. Why do they not "stop" there? Since passing through the battery will send them to a region with a negative charge which should repel them?

Comment: Is that a picture of a battery that is short circuited? Batteries are not mystery boxes that have electrons stored in it like marbles, batteries are electrochemical cells and the electrons are part of the chemical reactions that happen in the cell. What battery are you talking about?

Comment: When I was about 5 yrs old, my mum caught me switching off all the wall sockets. She asked me why - when my dad found out he was laughing: apparently I was worried all the electricity would collect in a puddle on the floor.

Comment: Conventional current flows from positive to negative.

Comment: FYI there's a schematic editor built in to the site. If you [Edit] your question and use the 'Schematic' button or Ctrl-M it'll pop up.

Comment: @Andyaka but the electrons themselves move towards positively charged elements no? So this would be neg->positive flow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It takes energy to pile up free electrons into one end of the battery since electrons want to repel each other. Naturally, you don't want this to happen in a battery that you want to keep running since the repulsion of the electrons would quickly reach equilibrium with the the energy being produced by the battery to move them and bring everything to a standstill.

But, the electrons are piling up in a sense. After all, they can't just disappear but the catch is *free* electrons. They are piling up but do not remain as as free electrons. What is happening is that there are two different chemical reactions occurring at the anode and cathode working in tandem. At the cathode there is an exothermic chemical reaction that releases both energy and free electrons, and at the anode there is another chemical reaction that consumes free electrons, incorporating them into the product molecule.

The reaction at the anode does not also necessarily need to be exothermic. It could be endothermic; It just needs to consume less energy than is produced by the reaction at the cathode so that the battery produces a net positive of energy.

In this way, the battery produces energy with the electrons as the energy carriers, and generates new free electrons that pile up at the cathode thus repelling each other to move towards the anode through the circuit (there is a barrier inside the battery separating the anode and cathode), while the reaction at the anode prevents the electrons from piling up there which would result in repulsion that would eventually stop the flow of energy and electrons.

When charging a rechargeable battery, everything is opposite in terms of energy and electrons.

Comment: The energy required to push free electrons together is also (literally) astronomical, which is why it really does not happen. Milliamps piling up for a few seconds in the tiny area of a battery terminal would repel each other with the force of rocket engine. That force makes sure that electrons keep flowing.

Comment: @user1850479 I believe that is the same reason why there's nothing like "electrons piling up on one end of a resistor" that beginners often ask. I'm not a physicist so I'm not sure of all the details but my understanding from what I read was that theoretically they do pile up but the energy is so large that the pile up is unmeasurable between the ends of the resistor since it only takes a near infinitesmal amount of piling up to meet the energy equilibrium of the circuit

Comment: First sentence is problematic. Place a free negative charge on a spiky conducting object and electrons will pile up at the spikes, despite their mutual repulsion and without energy 'input'.

Comment: @SredniVashtar How should I reword it?

Comment: I'd avoid to say what you cannot do, but focus instead on what you can do. You can pile up electrons by supplying energy by means of the internal reactions. Then I'd try to explain that the piling up ends when a certain equilibrium is reached. And how that equilibrium is altered when the battery is connected to a load. I reckon it would be a long answer. (And that's why I didn't write one :-) )

Comment: @SredniVashtar Reworded it slightly since I want this answer to remain legible.

Answer (score 2):

> Since **electrons** are negatively charged, the **current** will flow towards
> the positive side of the battery. Why do they not "stop" there? Since
> passing through the battery...

Current is the flow of *charge*, not necessarily electrons.

The electrons don't pass through the battery. They come out from the negative terminal and go back into the positive terminal, and that's it.

[Here's](https://www.chemistryworld.com/news/why-have-lithium-ion-batteries-just-won-the-chemistry-nobel-prize/4010479.article) an illustration of how it works in a Li-ion battery:-
[image]

When charging the battery, the charger sucks electrons out of the cathode ('+' terminal), and pushes electrons into the anode ('-' terminal). This 'pumps' lithium ions through the electrolyte from the cathode (+) to the anode (-). The electrons can't move through the electrolyte, so they all 'pile up' at the anode.

When an external circuit is connected the electrons flow through the wires from the anode back to the cathode, and the lithium ions move back through the electrolyte to meet them.

It is the *ions* inside the battery that transport charge. Thus current flows there, but electrons don't.

The other important thing to note is that no matter how much current flows, each electron only does (at most) one round trip from one plate to the other, while each ion shuttles from one side of the battery to the other.

This is why a battery can only store a limited amount of charge. Once all the ions have been pushed from one side to the other, that's it - the battery is 'full'.